# SOLID and C# events

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I'm currently learning the SOLID (OO Design) and something bugs me: the dependency inversion principle, according to which the upper policy layer should be able to comply with a lower one's interface, made me wonder; where do `event`'s fit in?

For example (taken from *"Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#"*):

[image]

Here, when the button is turned on/off, it calls `turnOn`/`turnOff` on the `ButtonServer` it would have some reference to.

Now if several objects were to depend on one single button, in order for this to work (imo), the button would have to store a list of `ButtonServer`'s and then call on each one's `turnOn`/`turnOff`.
This looks to me like reinventing what `event` already does.

Now if that button were to have a new state, **sleep**, we'd have to create a new interface `ButtonServerSleep` (or some other name) and we'd have to store a new different list of each `ButtonServerSleep` which would be depending on the button*. And will just end up writing the same kind of code for looping through `ButtonServer` and call `turnOn`/`turnOff` than for looping through `ButtonServerSleep` and call `sleep`, the kind of code to which `event`'s were made to avoid.

* if this would break the SRP, tell me.

Comment: I'm not a fan of blindly-following any patterns, but as I understand it, if several devices (`Lamps`) would need to depend on a single button, then a single `ButtonServer` (and a single `Button`) would be the ones responsible for sending the `turnOff/On` command to the lamps (via events if needed), but you wouldn't need to have many different `ButtonServers`. The idea here is that a button doesn't know what it ends up doing, it just "sends commands" to a "server" whose contract defines what it can do (and can be injected), and that server is responsible for the actual actions.

Comment: why would you create ButtonServerSleep for a new state?

Comment: @Jcl then what does the server do? The very same thing, send "turnOn/Off" to a list of object, and the question remain : event was created for this purpose, yet do we proceed otherwise?

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook yes, the buttonserver is a "man in the middle" between the lamps and the buttons. Should your implementation of what a "turn off/turn on" means, you can just inject a different implementation of that interface, without changing any code in either the button or the lamps. Should you go to "lamps subscribing to the button events", if it ever changes, you would need to change every type of either button, or lamp. The "real world" implications don't really make sense with buttons and lamps (which hopefully will only do one thing and never change), but think more widely

Comment: Events are merely a built-in observer pattern. See if your book talks about observers anywhere, and that's where events would fit in.

Answer (score 1):

The example with buttons and lamps is quite hard to follow, but I'll try:

```
public class Button
{
   IButtonServer _buttonServer;
   private bool _amIOn;

   public Button(IButtonServer buttonServer)
   {
      _buttonServer = buttonServer;
   }
   void Poll()
   {
     _amIOn = !_amIOn;
     if(_amIOn) _buttonServer.TurnOn(); else _buttonServer.TurnOff();
   }
}

interface ITurnOnOffableDevice
{
   void TurnOn();
   void TurnOff();
}

interface IButtonServer : ITurnOnOffableDevice
{
   void RegisterDevice(ITurnOnOffableDevice l);
}

public Lamp : ITurnOffableDevice
{
   public Lamp(IButtonServer buttonServer)
   {
     buttonServer.RegisterDevice(this);
   }
   public void TurnOn()
   {
     Shine();
   }
   public void TurnOff()
   {
     Darken();
   } 
}

public MeatTriturator : ITurnOffableDevice
{
   public MeatTriturator(IButtonServer buttonServer)
   {
     buttonServer.RegisterDevice(this);
   }
   public void TurnOn()
   {
     Triturate();
   }
   public void TurnOff()
   {
     ShutItDown();
   } 
}
```

Now, on some DLL which doesn't know about lamps, or meat triturators, you have this:

```
public ButtonServer : IButtonServer
{
   private List<ITurnOnOffableDevice> _devices = new List<ITurnOnOffAbleDevice>();

   public void RegisterDevice(ITurnOnOffAbleDevice l)
   {
     _devices.Add(l);
   }
   public void TurnOn()
   {
     foreach(var l in _devices) { l.TurnOn(); }
   }
   public void TurnOff()
   {
     foreach(var l in _devices) { l.TurnOff(); }
   }
}
```

Then you create everything:

```
public static IButtonServer MyLampAndTrituratorButtonServer;

static void Prepare()
{
   DependencyInject.ForType<IButtonServer>.Create<ButtonServer>();
}

static void Main()
{
   Prepare();

   MyLampAndTrituratorButtonServer = DependencyInject.CreateObject<IButtonServer>();

   // The MyLampAndTrituratorButtonServer could be injected directly in the
   // constructor of these objects, but for clarity I've left the normal
   // object declaration

   // this button will turn on lamps and meat triturators
   var button = new Button(MyLampAndTrituratorButtonServer);

   // these lamp and meat tritutator will be turned on/off by
   // the buttons in that server
   var lamp = new Lamp(MyLampAndTrituratorButtonServer);
   var meatTriturator = new MeatTriturator(MyLampAndTrituratorButtonServer);
}
```

Then somewhere else, deep inside your program, you have the need to create a new button that lights up that lamp and meat triturator, you'd just do:

```
   var button = new Button(MyLampAndTrituratorButtonServer);
```

No reference whatsoever to the actual lamp, or the meat triturator.

*(Or better yet: create the button while injecting the `IButtonServer` dependency on the constructor parameter (this would depend on your dependency injector, so I'm not giving code), but then you'd neither need the reference to `MyLampAndTrituratorButtonServer`)*

With this, you have decoupled your buttons from your lamps or meat triturators. The action of turning off and on is done by the button server, which as you can 
see is injected, so it could be anything (anything that implements IButtonServer).

So you have delegated the responsibility of turning on and off the devices to a single dependency.

Again, in the "real world", buttons tend to do just one thing, and lamps only turn off and on, and this is dubious to change in the future... but this is an example of delegating the responsibility to a single point.

But let's take it a bit further... imagine your requirements have changed, and the buttons which turn on/off lamps and meat triturators (and only those, not all buttons), need to have a security measure. Whenever they are turned on, they need to auto-shutdown in 30 seconds.

With your "events based approach", you would need to derive one object from "button" (i.e., `ButtonThatTurnsOffAt30secs : Button`) and change -everywhere- where a lamp or meat triturator is created, then recompile.

With the isolated dependency, you'd just rewrite your buttonserver:

```
public ButtonServerThatTurnsOffAt30seconds : IButtonServer
{
   private List<ITurnOnOffableDevice> _devices = new List<ITurnOnOffAbleDevice>();

   public void RegisterDevice(ITurnOnOffAbleDevice l)
   {
     _devices.Add(l);
   }
   public void TurnOn()
   {
     foreach(var l in _devices) { l.TurnOn(); new Timer(30, () => { TurnOff(); } }
   }
   public void TurnOff()
   {
     foreach(var l in _devices) { l.TurnOff(); }
   }
}
```

And change your dependency injection:

```
DependencyInject.ForType<IButtonServer>.Create<ButtonServerThatTurnsOffAt30seconds>();
```

If you have separated your project right, you wouldn't even need to recompile the whole application, just a single DLL change (or two if you have the dependency injector bootstrap on a different one) and voilá, now all your lamps and meat triturators turn off at 30 seconds.

Again, this is not the best example, and it made making an example hard, but I hope you can follow.

As a disclaimer: I'm trying to make a value on dependency isolation, not aiming to explain SOLID principles or any pattern, since you seem confused on that. I myself don't "follow patterns blindly", I just find whatever I find interesting on all those patterns and use it for a good purpose.

**If** you are sure your buttons will never change (or **ALL** your buttons will change at the same time), then there's no need for all of these. Whether going full-throttle on this, or whether to apply the GTD (*Getting Things Done*) principle, is up to you.

Applying patterns, decoupling dependencies, etc., takes time and effort, and depending on the project, deadline, budget, and possibility of it changing in the future, they are worth implementing or not.

Comment: Disclaimer 2: This was quickly crafted directly on the stackoverflow editor and I'm not in the best state of mind today (that's why I chose to spend some time here instead of doing actual work ;-) ), so I may be off at many points. Sorry about that if that's the case, just hope this got you on track to understand the benefits of dependency decoupling